# VBA activating a cell with a cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a very simple line of code that should activate a cell on another sheet but in the same workbook but I can't figure out why it doesn't work:

```
Sheets("me").Range(Cells(rownum, colnum)).Activate
```

It give an "application or object defined" error. `rownum` and `colnum` are defined variables and when hovering them in debug mode they show integer values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate the worksheet before you activate a cell on it.

Try this instead:

```
Public Sub test()
  With Sheets("me")
   .Activate
   .Cells(rownum, colnum).Activate
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

From Excel 2003 help:
Activates a single cell, **which must be inside the current selection**. To select a range of cells, use the Select method.

---

By the way, do you REALLY need to activate or select that range ? In 90% of the code I see, those `.Select` are totally unnecessary !

Comment: It is a quick check to jump from a cell on the current sheet to a corresponding cell on another sheet to see it's value. It's not part of a wider routine.